# Rank Tree in C++

Tags: c++, boost, stl, tree, multiway-tree

We need ADT having search and rank features.
That is, in addition to the interface of STL map, a function 'int get_rank(key)' is required.

Standard implementation of such function requires supporting and updating an extra integer field in every node of self-balanced searching tree (e.g., in black-red tree, used in STL map/set).
But it seems, STL map/set do not do this.

We're looking for a solution based on standard containers (STL, Boost) having the best possible Time Complexity:
  finding/adding/erasing an element take O(log n) (like in STL map/set), 
  computing the rank by a key takes also O(log n).

By the rank of an element, we mean the position of the element in the sorted sequence of all the elements of the map/set.

Example.
  set = {0, 4, 6, 7, 8}
  rank(0)=1, rank(4)=2, rank(6)=3, rank(7)=4, rank(8)=5.

In our opinion, under Time Complexity constrains above, the problem cannot be solved by a combination of two maps one sorting by key and other sorting by rank.

Thanks.

Comment: The complexities of search, insert and delete are often inversely related to each other.  We can't decide which trade-off is best for you.

Comment: There is an implementation of rank tree satisfying all the time complexity constrains, see, e.g., the book of Cormen, T.H. "Introduction to Algorithms".

Comment: **It can be done with GNU extension in the `libstdc++`, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23095152/341970).**

Answer (score 5):

The rank of the given key K is the number of keys which are less or equal to K.

E.g., let set s = {1, 3, 4, 6, 9}.
Then rank(1) = 1, rank(4) = 3, rank(9) = 5.

The STL function distance() can be used for computing the rank of an element x appearing in the set s.

rank = distance(s.begin(), s.find(x));

The problem is that its time complexity is O(n).

Note that proposed two maps (or sets) indexed by key and by rank is not correct solution.
The problem is that a change of one element affects ranks of many others.
E.g., adding element 0 to the set s above change the ranks of all existing elements:
s' = {0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 9}.
rank(1) = 2, rank(4) = 4, rank(9) = 6.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented a "ranked red-black tree" which is similar to a red-black tree except each node stores the distance from the node that precedes it via an in-order traversal, rather than storing a key.

This does exactly what you want, except the "rank" of the first node is 0 and not 1 (you can add/subtract 1 if needed).

My solution is PUBLIC DOMAIN and is based on a public domain tutorial for a regular red-black tree. All operations -- including insert, remove, find, and determine rank have logarithmic time with respect to the number of elements in the data structure.

You can find it here:
http://code.google.com/p/options/downloads/list

You should get the latest version from the above link, currently (as of this writing) rrb_v4_release.cpp.

Answer (score 1):

you can use some other map like containers .
keep a size fields can make binary search tree easy to random access .
here is my implementation ...
std style , random access iterator ...
size balanced tree ...
https://github.com/mm304321141/zzz_lib/blob/master/sbtree.h
and B+tree ...
https://github.com/mm304321141/zzz_lib/blob/master/bpptree.h

Comment: Nice library. But why not provide some notes in English?

Comment: I have a question. You have 2 specializations for sbtree: multimap and multiset. What about a regular map and set? Overall, a very useful classes, Cheers) Was looking for a while something like that. Can't see a reason why standard libs do not have weigh-balanced containers in them.

Comment: one of my other project need a rank supported multimap ... i public it after that ...

Answer (score -1):

I would suppose that by `rank` you actually mean the distance from the root, since if it could be stored contiguously with the value you would not have to go to such length.

I think you could do it "externally", since in this case the rank can be extrapolated from the number of times the comparison predicate is used...

```
namespace detail
{
  template <class Comparator>
  class CounterComparator: Comparator
  {
  public:
    CounterComparator(size_t& counter):
        Comparator(), mCounter(&counter) {}
    CounterComparator(Comparator comp, size_t& counter):
        Comparator(comp), mCounter(&counter) {}

    template <class T, class U>
    bool operator()(T& lhs, U& rhs) const
    { 
      ++(*mCounter);
      return this->Comparator::operator()(lhs,rhs);
    }
  private:
    size_t* mCounter;
  };
} // namespace detail

template <
  class Key, 
  class Value, 
  class Cmp = std::less<Key>, 
  class Allocator = std::allocator< std::pair<const Key,Value> >
>
class SuperMap
{
  typedef detail::CounterComparator<Cmp> Comparator;
public:
  SuperMap(): mCounter(0), mData(Comparator(mCounter)) {}

  Value& operator[](const Key& key) { return mData[key]; }

  size_t rank(const Key& key) const
  { 
    mCounter = 0; mData.find(key); return mCounter;
  }

private:
  typedef std::map<Key,Value, Comparator, Allocator> data_type;

  mutable size_t mCounter;
  data_type mData;
}; // class SuperMap

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  SuperMap<int,int> superMap;
  superMap[1] = 42;
  std::cout << superMap.rank(1) << std::endl;
}

// outputs
// 2
```

It counts the number of tests, but since `std::map` stops testing as soon as it gets the right key... it should be alright :) Though there is probably some offset to deduce there (1 or 2) to get the rank instead.

If you gave a better definition of `rank` I may work a bit more but I don't want to spend too much time in the wrong direction.